# How to properly make an IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, select, ienumerable

C# Error CS0411 in .Select
I have code for reading Excel tables, in it I count rows and columns.

```
public class Table
{
    private double[,]? excelTable;
    private int totalRows = 0;
    private int totalColumns = 0;
    ExcelPackage excelFile = new ExcelPackage(@"D:telegram bot/Excel_Ankets.xlsx");
    public Task List(string[] _excelTable)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
        totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
        excelTable = new double[totalRows, totalColumns];
        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= totalRows; rowIndex++)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> row = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString);

            
            List<string> list = row.ToList<string>();

            for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                excelTable[rowIndex - 1, i] = Convert.ToDouble(list[i].Replace('.', ','));
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < totalColumns; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(excelTable[i, j]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

in line "IEnumerable row = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString);"
gives an error CS0411, help solve the problem

I climbed on different sites and similar problems. In fact, these problems were not so similar, I did not solve anything

Comment: The braces are missing at the first line of code inside the first for-loop. So you just forgot the "()" braces after **ToString**. Instead of **ToString** you need to write **ToString()**.

Here is the correct code:

`IEnumerable<string> row = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString());`

Comment: Thank you, I changed the code a little so that it worked, and the error has already disappeared, but now the console reaches "Start Task" and then the code is not completed (checked with other Console.WriteLine) 
` ` ` Console.WriteLine("Start Task"); ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1]; totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; excelTable = new double[totalRows, totalColumns]; for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= totalRows; rowIndex++) ` ` `

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I call the Task which is in the Table method:

var tb = new Table();
tb.List();

Task does not execute code (Inserted beginning of Task):

ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
        totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
        excelTable = new double[totalRows, totalColumns];

However if I write 1 or 2 Console.WriteLine they will execute.
What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the braces of the `ToString()-Method`. Because of this you have got two types as result of the select: string or `Func<string>`. You need to add those braces at the first line of code inside the first for-loop. Just replace the whole line with the `ToString()` method but with braces.

**Fixed Code:**

```
IEnumerable<string> row = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString());
```

The Select can't see if you want a `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<Func<<string>>`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the code a little so that it worked, and the error has already disappeared, but now the console reaches "Start Task" and then the code is not completed (checked with other Console.WriteLine)


` ` `
Console.WriteLine("Start Task");
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
        totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
        excelTable = new double[totalRows, totalColumns];
        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= totalRows; rowIndex++)
` ` `